# python user input autocompletion tab

Tags: python

I want to make a CLI application for my project, Like this
Example:

```
Enter: se<TAB>
set search
Enter: set <TAB>
username password
```

when the user presses the tab the following text comes which is present in that list containing option and if the text complete(**For Example set**), So if the user press tab after **set** the following option will come **username and password**. Thanks :)
(I Think  **if text.startswith("set")** may work)

Comment: This should be reopened, because the dupe target is about how to do tab completion in Python, but about how to _recursive_ tab completion, which is far more complex, as you can see in the example I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think they have the perfect example at [Pymotw](https://pymotw.com/2/readline/#accessing-the-completion-buffer) - the only bad thing is that it doesn't work with Python 3 as-is - it is written for Python 2. Below is a Python 3 version:

```py
import readline
import logging

LOG_FILENAME = '/tmp/completer.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    )

class BufferAwareCompleter(object):
    def __init__(self, options):
        self.options = options
        self.current_candidates = []

    def complete(self, text, state):
        response = None
        if state == 0:
            # This is the first time for this text, so build a match list.
            
            origline = readline.get_line_buffer()
            begin = readline.get_begidx()
            end = readline.get_endidx()
            being_completed = origline[begin:end]
            words = origline.split()

            logging.debug('origline = %s', repr(origline))
            logging.debug('begin = %s', begin)
            logging.debug('end = %s', end)
            logging.debug('being_completed = %s', being_completed)
            logging.debug('words = %s', words)
            
            if not words:
                self.current_candidates = sorted(self.options.keys())
            else:
                try:
                    if begin == 0:
                        # first word
                        candidates = self.options.keys()
                    else:
                        # later word
                        first = words[0]
                        candidates = self.options[first]
                    
                    if being_completed:
                        # match options with portion of input
                        # being completed
                        self.current_candidates = [w for w in candidates if w.startswith(being_completed)]
                    else:
                        # matching empty string so use all candidates
                        self.current_candidates = candidates

                    logging.debug('candidates = %s', self.current_candidates)
                    
                except (KeyError, IndexError) as err:
                    logging.error('completion error: %s', err)
                    self.current_candidates = []
        
        try:
            response = self.current_candidates[state]
        except IndexError:
            response = None
        logging.debug('complete(%s, %s) => %s', repr(text), state, response)
        return response
            

def input_loop():
    line = ''
    while line.strip() != 'stop':
        line = input('Prompt ("stop" to quit): ')
        print('Dispatch %s' % line)

# Register our completer function
readline.set_completer(BufferAwareCompleter(
    {'list':['files', 'directories'],
     'print':['byname', 'bysize'],
     'stop':[],
    }).complete)

# Use the tab key for completion
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')

# Prompt the user for text
input_loop()
```

Comment: @sysinfo please don't post comments like `Thank you` or `Thanks` - instead, just upvote the answer and, if possible, accept it.